# mongodb load document and increment counter

Tags: mongodb

Maybe this sounds bit strange but i will ask it.

In my application i store posts in my collection called `posts`. It looks like this

```
{
   _id: 123,
   name: "somename",
   surname: "somesurname",
   img: "path/to/img",
   views: 0
}
```

So is it possible in mongodb to increase the `views` everytime that document gets loaded? Or do i need an workaround?

My other solution is after i fetch all data with `.find()` or `.aggregate()` to map all the `_id`s and execute an update query with `$in` to increase everywhere the views by 1. I hope you know what i mean.

But i think its kinda in-efficient, because i need 2 querys. I was also thinking about, instead of using querys like `.find()`, to use update querys and return the new document with `new: true`. Is this possible, can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing 100% native OTB within MongoDB, but here are some approaches I recommend:

**Option 1: Application Data Layer (Recommended)**

Standardize this on the data layer of your application. On every access operation (that you deem to be a notable "view"), remember the IDs of the retrieved posts, and *after* you server the request, run a multi-update to increment this number.

This "multi-update" approach will make sure that you're minimizing your increment update ops. You can even "remember" these in memory and run the updates in batch just once in a while (assuming you're OK that "views" might be out of date by a few minutes).

You do not want to have your API wait on this data increment operation, because you will slow down all your read operations. If you need to return data with updated numbers, then updated them in memory before returning, but still do the DB views update after serving the request.

**Why I strongly recommend this option:** there will always be cases when you'll read the post, but not want to increment the "view" counter, like when you're doing internal analytics, or checking data for other internal operations. There are also cases when you'll just do an update, which is not a strict "view", but you'll want to update the view counter, because you're still serving the result for "viewing". So maintaining logical "Data Layer" control over what is really a view, is a very good practice.

**Option 2: Use Mongo Stitch**

If you were using something like Mongo Stitch (https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/), this offers such functionality naturally (https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/#database-trigger), but then you might as well handle much of your application with this additional layer (if it's even available to you).

**Option 3: Use MongoDB Stored JavaScript**

In SQL DBs you would use triggers, and the closest thing in "raw" MongoDB is "Stored JavaScript", BUT there is no natural way (AFAIK) to trigger this stored JS on document access, so you'd have to integrate this into something like Option 1 anyway, so it's just a noteworthy solution mention.

Comment: well cool answer, i will read about stitch and look how i can implement this

Comment: when you said remember the IDs and do an multy update, do you mean for example storing them in an redis cache for example, and run an linux cron job script that is executing every 10 min for example an multy update with that data?

Comment: @Ifaruki There are many approaches to that "optimization" part, using redis and cron jobs is probably more on the complex side :), but all's well that works well for you. If using Node.JS, I would personally just store updated views in common JS memory and "flush" once in a while with a multi update, but of course that could cause some loss if your server goes down with unsaved views, so it just depends on how critical your data is.. Either way, I would start without this part, it may well be unnecessary altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, directly you can increment by updating the collection

```
db.posts.update({ _id: { $inc: { views: 1 } })
```

For more, you can see the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/